# Cuda how to copy char** from kernel to host

Tags: c++, c, cuda

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ void kern_2D(char **desc, char** merge_char) {

    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    int idy = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;

    if (idx < 10000)
    {
        char* s1 = desc[idx];
        merge_char[idx] = s1;
        //printf("From key = %s\n", merge_char[idx]);
    }

}


int main() {
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
    size_t max_line_len = 255;
    char line[255];
    size_t line_len;
    size_t max_lines_desc = 10000;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    char **d_desc;
    cudaMalloc(&d_desc, max_lines_desc * sizeof(char *));

    char **m_desc = NULL;
    m_desc = (char**)malloc(max_lines_desc * sizeof(char**));
    char **d_temp_desc = NULL;
    d_temp_desc = (char **)malloc(max_lines_desc * sizeof(char **));

    FILE *f_desc = fopen("desc.txt", "r");
    if (!f_desc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!\n");
    }
    int idesc = 0;

    do
    {
        if (!fgets(line, max_line_len, f_desc))
        {
            if (ferror(f_desc) && !feof(f_desc))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from file!\n");
                fclose(f_desc);
            }
            break;
        }

        line_len = strlen(line);
        if ((line_len > 0) && (line[line_len - 1] == '\n'))
        {
            line[line_len - 1] = '\0';
            --line_len;
        }
        m_desc[idesc] = line;
        cudaMalloc(&(d_temp_desc[idesc]), sizeof(line) * sizeof(char));
        cudaMemcpy(d_temp_desc[idesc], m_desc[idesc], sizeof(line) * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(d_desc + idesc, &(d_temp_desc[idesc]), sizeof(char *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        ++idesc;
    } while (idesc < max_lines_desc);
    fclose(f_desc);

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


    char **merge_char;
    cudaMallocManaged(&merge_char, max_lines_desc * sizeof(char *));


    kern_2D << < 1, 1000 >> > (d_desc , merge_char);

    err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %s after launching addKernel!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    }


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    char** h_dev;

    cudaMalloc((void**)(&h_dev), max_lines_desc * sizeof(char*));
    err = cudaMemcpy(h_dev, merge_char, max_lines_desc * sizeof(char*), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (err == cudaSuccess) printf("2: Okay \n");


    for (int i = 0; i < max_lines_desc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", h_dev[i]);
    }


    return 0;


}
//nvcc - arch = sm_30 - o kernel kernel.cu
// cuda - memcheck . / kernel
```

I'm sorry for my mistake. I already updated my code. It's completed.

For desc.txt, the file has 10000 lines like below. I checked status after copy from device to host, but I'm wrong. I cannot print char** h_dev.

> motorcycle ckd
>   new apsonic
>   ckd 2017
>   ckd 2018
>   motorcycle apsoni
>   new motorcycle apsonic
>   no 125
>   motorcycle apsonic ap125
>   new motorcycle apsonic ap125

Comment: @Robert Crovella . Can you help me in this case ?

Comment: I assume know the length of the arrays from that code fragment, or are they dynamic or for example null terminated (since the example does not make much sense)? What is `s1` and `s2` being used for and how?

Comment: Hi, I just run this code and it's fine. And i want copy char** merge_char back to host. But i can't. The lenght of array is 10000

Comment: I'm not sure, why this code even compile, since s2 is not defined.
Anyway, if you want to copy output to host memory, you need to use cudaMemcpy - https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc263dbe6574220cc776b45438fc351e8 with "cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost" as the last argument

Comment: ohoh, sorry, this my mistake. I used that but cannot copy.

Comment: If you want to show a complete code, I will take a look as time permits.  By complete I mean a [mcve].  A kernel, by itself, is not a [mcve].  It should be a complete code that I can copy, paste, compile, and run.  For example I want to see how you are allocating for `desc` and `merge_char` and also how you are copying `desc` from host to device.  Don't just provide that, however.  If you don't provide a *complete* [mcve], I won't spend any time on this.

Comment: Hello @RobertCrovella , I updated my code. it's completed. I cannot print h_dev. I met error :  In page error reading location 0x0000000701CD3A00 (status code 0xC0000022).

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I don't really understand what your intent is here, because the only thing your kernel is doing is swapping pointers.  If that is all you intend to do, you are certainly making things difficult for yourself by using double pointers everywhere.  It would be far simpler just to manage the indices.

But to address your question, as far as I can tell your "copy back to host" is indeed incorrect.  You are effectively doing a deep-copy of your data from host to device, and so you will need a deep-copy (2-stage copy) in the other direction as well.

To accomplish that, we don't use `cudaMalloc` on the copy to host.  `cudaMalloc` allocates device memory.  If you want to copy something to the host, your copy target is host memory.  So we will need a set of `cudaMemcpy` operations to deep-copy the data back to the host, using host buffers as the targets.

The following code represents the simplest modifications I could make to what you have shown to accomplish this, and it seems to work for me for my simple test case:

```
$ cat desc.txt
1motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap125
2motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap125
3motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap125
4motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap125
5motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap125
6motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap1
$ cat t301.cu
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ void kern_2D(char **desc, char** merge_char) {

    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    int idy = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;

    if (idx < 10000)
    {
        char* s1 = desc[idx];
        merge_char[idx] = s1;
        //printf("From key = %s\n", merge_char[idx]);
    }

}


int main() {
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
    size_t max_line_len = 255;
    char line[255];
    size_t line_len;
    size_t max_lines_desc = 10000;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    char **d_desc;
    cudaMalloc(&d_desc, max_lines_desc * sizeof(char *));

    char **m_desc = NULL;
    m_desc = (char**)malloc(max_lines_desc * sizeof(char**));
    char **d_temp_desc = NULL;
    d_temp_desc = (char **)malloc(max_lines_desc * sizeof(char **));

    FILE *f_desc = fopen("desc.txt", "r");
    if (!f_desc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!\n");
    }
    int idesc = 0;

    do
    {
        if (!fgets(line, max_line_len, f_desc))
        {
            if (ferror(f_desc) && !feof(f_desc))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from file!\n");
                fclose(f_desc);
            }
            break;
        }

        line_len = strlen(line);
        if ((line_len > 0) && (line[line_len - 1] == '\n'))
        {
            line[line_len - 1] = '\0';
            --line_len;
        }
        m_desc[idesc] = line;
        cudaMalloc(&(d_temp_desc[idesc]), sizeof(line) * sizeof(char));
        cudaMemcpy(d_temp_desc[idesc], m_desc[idesc], sizeof(line) * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(d_desc + idesc, &(d_temp_desc[idesc]), sizeof(char *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        ++idesc;
    } while (idesc < max_lines_desc);
    fclose(f_desc);

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


    char **merge_char;
    cudaMallocManaged(&merge_char, max_lines_desc * sizeof(char *));


    kern_2D << < 1, 1000 >> > (d_desc , merge_char);

    err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %s after launching addKernel!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    }


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    char** h_dev;

    h_dev = (char **)malloc(max_lines_desc * sizeof(char*));
    err = cudaMemcpy(h_dev, merge_char, max_lines_desc * sizeof(char*), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (err == cudaSuccess) printf("2: Okay \n");


    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cudaMemcpy(line, h_dev[i], sizeof(line), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }


    return 0;


}
$ nvcc -o t301 t301.cu
t301.cu(15): warning: variable "idy" was declared but never referenced

$ cuda-memcheck ./t301
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
2: Okay
1motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap125
2motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap125
3motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap125
4motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap125
5motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap125
6motorcycle ckd new apsonic ckd 2017 ckd 2018 motorcycle apsoni new motorcycle apsonic no 125 motorcycle apsonic ap125 new motorcycle apsonic ap1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Oh my god. I understood with your comment. I just learn cuda from some your post on stackoverflow. So I just run swap pointer. I did cuda with an integer, it's okay. And i change to char** and got the error. But your comments make me need to back cuda and learn again.